# Why super referes to current object in the below Java Example

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass, super

```
class Animal {
    String color = "white";
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    void printColor() {
        System.out.println("This Color: " + color); //prints color of Dog class  
        System.out.println("Parent Color: " + super.color); //prints color of Animal class  
    }
}

class TestSuper1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.color = "black";
        d.printColor();
    }
}
```

In the output "Parent Color" is printing "black" which confusing me. It should be "white" right since I have changed the color of Child object only ? Could anybody please explain me the reason.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to indent your code consistently and readably. (It's also a good idea when *not* asking for help.) I've reformatted it for you above.

Comment: Thank you ! Will take care of it in future.

Answer (score 3):

> It should be "white" right since I have changed the color of Child
>   object only

You have not 2 objects but 1.

`color` is inherited in the child class.
Invoking `super.color` or `color` is the same thing as you have a single `color` field.

Add a `color` field to the `Dog` class and it will produce a distinct result :

```
class Dog extends Animal {
   ...
    String color = "white";
    void printColor() {
        System.out.println("This Color: " + color);// prints color of Dog class
        System.out.println("Parent Color: " + super.color);// prints color of Animal class
     }
}
```

Now you  will get two distinct outputs when you write :

```
Dog d = new Dog();
d.color = "black"; // modify the color field of Dog not which one of Animal
d.printColor();
```

as the first output refers to the `Dog` field and the the second output refers to the `Animal` field.

Comment: I don't think introducing field overriding when it isn't present in the question is remotely useful. All it does is *further* confuse someone who already thinks there are separate objects.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I get you. I introduced a new field declaration in the subclass (instances fields are not overridden)  to show how the OP could get the result that he/she expects. While explaining that a single object and so a single `color` field was created/used. I had the impression that explaining only the second one missed something...

Comment: (My comment above wasn't answering your first comment, btw; just coincidence.)

Comment: @davidxxx : Yes this was what exactly made me confused. After adding 'color' field in the subclass I was able to call super and I could access super class object's color filed. Actually super class object is not created implicitly while we creating a child class object?

Comment: "Actually super class object is not created implicitly while we creating a child class object? " Yes. You get it.

Answer (score 1):

`color` is only declared once, in the super class `Animal`. `Dog` itself does not have a slot named `color` exclusive to itself.

Since Dog is a subclass, it inherits the slot from Animal.

Answer (score 1):

There is only **one** object, and it has only **one** `color` member. The only difference between referring to it via `this` (as you are implicitly; inside `printColor`, `color` and `this.color` are the same thing) or via `super` is the *type* of reference you have to it and some details around how that type information is used. You're still referring to the same object. There is only one `color` member in that object. And since there is only one, and you can access it via `this` or `super`, you get the same result either way.

Comment: Super class object is first created upon the creation of child class object right? Here how can I get this super class object created and print the value of 'color' of that super class object then?

Comment: @Rajeesh: No. Again: There is only one object, which has all the features defined by both the superclass and the subclass. There are not separate objects. This is class-based inheritance, not prototypical inheritance (as used by some other languages, such as Self and JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

since the field `color` is defined only in Parent class `Animal`, then the object of child class `Dog` will set its value to "black" and child class has no field of name color that's why its value will print "black" in both the cases. But if we define a field `String color = "brown";` in `Dog` class then the output will be print : black color for `Dog` class and white color for `Animal` class.

Comment: My question is why super.color not printing 'white' if child class doesnt have its own color property?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers already explain what's happening in your code.

So what's the use of `super.xxx`? It means (more or less): take the current `this` object, but use the method and field declarations of the superclass.

`super` is mostly used with methods where your method overrides the parent's inherited method - but you don't want to have a completely new behaviour, just add functionality to your parent's implementation.

```
class Animal {
    String color = "white";
    void printColor() {
        System.out.println("Animal color: " + color); 
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    void printColor() {
        // Animal class prints the color
        // Dog class remarks that it's a dog
        System.out.println("I am a Dog!");  
        super.printColor(); 
    }
}

class TestSuper1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // declaring d as Dog or Animal doesn't matter
        Animal d = new Dog(); 
        d.color = "black";
        d.printColor();
    }
}
```

This will print

```
I am a Dog!
Animal color: black
```